# How to create typescript definition file for external package which returns class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-5, type-definition

There is an external npm package which doesn't support typescript:

```
const ClassA = class ClassA {
  constructor(options) {
    this.test = options => this.client(options)
    .then(ClassA._validateAddress.bind({
      ...options,
      address: this.address
    }))
    this.someMethod = options => this.test(options);

    ClassA._validateOptions(options);
    ClassA._validateAddress(options.address);

    this.address = options.address;
    this.log = options.log || console;
    this.client = otherPackage.defaults({
      defaultAddress: this.address,
      returns: true
    });
  }

  static _validateOptions(options) {
    if (!options) {
      throw new Error('test error')
    }
    if (!isObject(options)) {
      throw new Error('options is not an object');
    }

    function isObject(value) {
      const type = typeof value
      return value !== null && (type === 'object' || type === 'function')
    }
  }
}

module.exports = ClassA
```

I am creating something like this in my TypeScript project (still in JS, will be converted to TS):

```
const ClassA = require('package-without-ts')

const myClient = class ClassB extends ClassA {
  constructor(options) {
    super(...arguments)

    this.customMethod = options => Object.assign(options, {
      test: true
    })
  }
}


const options = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
const client = new myClient(options);
```

How to create a type definition for ClassA package, as I want to use it with my typescript project, I just started learning TS so this is bit complex for me to understand

I tried extracting class or interfaces in TS style to `.d.ts` file, but nothing works for me

```
/// <reference types="node" />


interface IOptions {
  address: string,
  log: object,
}

declare module 'package-without-ts' {
  class ClassA {
    public options: object
    constructor (options: IOptions) {
    }
  }
}
```

I expect my TS project to work with package which doesn't support TS

Answer (score 0):

You didn't export anything from your declared module `package-without-ts`.

Change to this

```js
declare module 'package-without-ts' {
  class ClassA {
    public options: object
    constructor (options: IOptions) // {} in your code is invalid
  }

  export = ClassA // special syntax for commonjs style export
}
```